# call c# function in XPC target of simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-guide, xpc-target

Is there any way to use C# function in XPC target of matlab. If yes, please let me more about how?

Thanks 
hadi

Comment: I don't know the _Xpc Target_ toolbox enough to bring a definitive answer, but I know enough about C# to answer this: a C# function needs several layers running on the host to be able to be executed. Namely it needs: (1) an **operating system**, (2) where **the `.net` framework is installed**. It means your _target_ processor must have an operating system **and** .net installed ... Seems unlikely to me that it will be the case if you need to use Xpc target.

Comment: Now `C#` is called this way because the syntax is as close as possible to the `C/C++` family of languages, so if your `C#` function does not extensively call other `.net` libraries, converting the function into something you can use in Matlab should be your easiest route.

Comment: I will test it, thanks Hoki